# Typeof typescript class is not assignable to that of a class which extends it

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

We have a base `StoreObject` class which provides general methods for transformations/sanitisation etc for objects being saved to a DB. I'd like to be able to specify stricter return types from these methods using generics. However, my attempts are leading to errors when comparing the `typeof StoreObject` to the `typeof AClassThatExtendsStoreObject`, a check we do in various utility function. Can you point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong in the below?

```js
class StoreObject<S> {
  toStoreObject(s: S): S {
    // Perform some sanitisation etc.
    return s;
  }
}

interface Fact {
  id: string;
  fact: string;
}

// A concrete implementation of StoreUnit where we attempt to define the actual model of the object being stored
class FactStoreObject extends StoreObject<Fact> {}

// We've got some general utils that interact objects using these classes 
// These typicallay take a concrete implementation of StoreUnit to be used as a parser/processer
function doSomething(StoreObjectClass: typeof StoreObject) {
  // Typically:
  // const parsedObject = new StoreObjectClass(someObject).toStoreObject()
  // persistToDb(parsedObject)
}

// This errors with "Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'Fact'"
doSomething(FactStoreObject);
```

[playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAYwNghgzlAEDKAXA9gJwKYHkBGArdIiAPPAHywDewssKSaWeBiAFFAFwICUn8l1NWAHohsAArpUAMzQBbWFGSz0CiADsAlog1QI25GtjpEIAHQCaGRAFdUhqAG4BAX2CvgGtYklSIIFQBifoj8NBoAJpxQiKieAOZONL6EUTHxTu4isACCsCAGIFYqGrIADmDoyl56GgawyFIIKBgAqpohAO4AFpIqHSp63mUhKLDh6FKeKog9sMEQ1mCwssjjSw20s8hMhLDY6PEKzejhoJAwsEGE9Bg4+LvoAB7eauFwN4z3xFeI5BSZogAkgByABuKjiyBCimUsDi6DUkggS2s2jAcBmelgpUkUB0IXU4VgUmMIC69R2iDgUlQSk2KgAIgAhYBZAAqPSg0wAnqUNCBkZBubQIABrAZ5ApFWAlcqVBGIGp1DYfNpaWjIPYqaxc05ZaBzbEQVBc1BCUq0-wwSTAKTWNSEWqGcLIeBKYxdeIsD53ZgAYXOHFovPQKuOvsIXFCwlEiF5-MF3IEWXyamiRpNJwjIQAvLBER0mgxswHoFA2O7s1xTHRw5SWFxk6IcSb8WzkAzsCxSsbdVW3MBWaIOTojKhaSbYB0tOSAERskOwYHwYEyuBqKFzGAaOJqCDYCoa4M4pc-YGz4Aut3KGZen4+ylcBxAA)

Comment: Can't you make `doSomething()` generic?  `FactStoreObject` cannot create generic `StoreObject<S>` instances... it can only make `StoreObject<Fact>` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided code, in the "doSomething" function, the parameter type is being specified as "StoreObject" without the generic type it is specting. In order to fix the error you would need to do something like:

1. Pass the generic parameter for "StoreObject" (*Fact* in this case) to *doSomthing*.
2. The *doSomething* function's parameter must specify a type with a constructor signature which allow creating a new instance.

   Here's the sample:

```
function doSomething<T>(StoreObjectClass: { new(): StoreObject<T> }) {
  // typically
  const someObject = <any>{id: "001", fact: "A real fact"};
  const parsedObject = new StoreObjectClass().toStoreObject(someObject);
  // persistToDb(parsedObject)
}

doSomething<Fact>(FactStoreObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is due to this line:

```
const parsedObject = new StoreObjectClass(someObject)
```

First, you need constructable interface:

```
export interface IConstructable<T> {
    new (): T;
}
```

Second, you need to include parameter of the type into your factory method:

```
function doSomething<T>( t: IConstructable<T> ) {
  const parsedObject = ( new t() ).toStoreObject();
  // persistToDb(parsedObject);
}
```

Comment: Despite we both get to basically the same solution, I would like to recognize the use of an interface for the constructor signature was an **elegant touch**.